# Calling Same delegate function in both Extended and mainContorllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a BaseController with alertDelegate Function

Here is the alertView

```
@interface BaseController : UIViewController

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
```

Suppose I have another ViewCOntorller that exstends my BaseController

```
@interface MainController : BaseController
```

The problem that I face is, When i call AlertView in my BaseController, If my MainController has alertDelegate

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{    
}
```

The alertView delegate is called only in MainController not in BaseController.

How I want to do this alert in every screen that extends BaseController. However its quite hard to copy paste same amount of code inside every controller. Is there any whay i can just call it inside BaseController since every controller extends it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly call the `super` delegate method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [super alertView:alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    // Do other stuff
}
```

This is because you've subclassed the view controller class and therefore any overridden methods are called instead of the superclass methods.  This includes any protocol methods, as they are considered to be no different.

Comment: Where i have to call it? In Main or in BaseController?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar In the derived class (`MainController`).

Comment: No Visible interface of BaseController declares the selector xxx. This is the error i get. -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView  IS ALREady a delegate function of alertView

Comment: @MuhammadUmar OK declare that the `BaseController` conforms to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` with `@interface BaseController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`.